# Set Label for textbox in extjs

Tags: extjs

I am very new to this ExtJS, Here is my POC,

```
   Ext.onReady(function(){


    var my3rdNumberField = new Ext.form.NumberField({
        xtype: 'numberfield', 
        selectOnFocus: true, 
        allowNegative: false,
        fieldLabel: 'Number of Copies',
        allowDecimals: false,
        name: 'noofcopy', 
        width: 25,
        value:1,
        maxValue:20,
        minValue:1
    });

    my3rdNumberField.render(Ext.getBody());


});
```

i gave the field label as Number of Copies, but it is not showing before the textbox or anywhere else. can you please help me where i have mistaken or is there anything i need to add along with the listed. if so why fieldLabel is not working?

Comment: i am trying in jsfiddle.net i am not familiar about versions

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisramakers/KUqM9/ in this

Answer (score 0):

change Ext.form.NumberField to Ext.form.field.Number.

```
var my3rdNumberField = new Ext.form.field.Number({
        xtype: 'numberfield', 
        selectOnFocus: true, 
        allowNegative: false,
        fieldLabel: 'Number of Copies',
        allowDecimals: false,
        name: 'noofcopy', 
        Labelwidth: 50,
        value:1,
        maxValue:20,
        minValue:1
    });
my3rdNumberField.render(Ext.getBody());
```

Comment: can you show me the working fiddle, i tried, your answer is not working as expected

Comment: can u try this same code in this link.http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Number.

Comment: copy in example usage of code editor and see the output in live preview

Comment: i cannot show my entire code. i just used this Ext.form.NumberField for this example. i cannot able to declare the type as u said number instread of number. i m putting this element in items array of a Ext.FormPanel. can you suggest any of that kind. that is adding some more attributes like that

Comment: let me try ...if possible can u please provide the output how you require.

Comment: one label and textbox. but the code should be inside  Ext.FormPanel items declaration. i am wondering other elements inside the form are having label and they have used in same format. they have labels. but what is the problem with my code. i have found it is similar.

Comment: check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hWGYE/2359/ ,it consists of numberfield in a formPanel.i think it can help you.

Comment: thanks but still if i used this code label is not coming. for other fields it is getting displayed

Answer (score 0):

here is working code in extjs 3.4 . please confirm the version of extjs.If you are using extjs 4 or above see the example :
http://jsfiddle.net/hWGYE/2358/

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    var myPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
         labelWidth: 120,
   items:[new Ext.form.NumberField({
       xtype: 'numberfield', 
       selectOnFocus: true, 
       allowNegative: false,
       fieldLabel: 'Number of Copies',
       allowDecimals: false,
       name: 'noofcopy', 
       width: 100,
       value:1,
       maxValue:20,
       minValue:1
   })],
 });
    myPanel.render(Ext.getBody());
});
```

Comment: thanks but still if i used this code label is not coming. for other fields it is getting displayed

Comment: for this item label is displayed 
xtype: 'textarea', fieldLabel: 'Subject', allowBlank: false, maxLength: 240, name: 'subject', height: 75, width: 200
and for my numberfield it is not coming